# Creating a filename field to later write to file

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation with the following fields:

```
foldername: foo
filebasename: bar
texttostore: foobarfoobarfoobar
```

I want to create a file in a folder named `foo` which is located at the same folder than the Kettle script. The filename must be called `bar.txt`.

I see that the step *Text file output* can get the filename from a field.

How can I create a filename that refers to file `./foo/bar.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

In the Text File Output step you can select `Accept file name from field?` and specifiy a field, eg. `filename`, in the incoming rows that contain the filename (including path, but excluding extension). You can construct this filename in a previous step, for example with a Formula step that constructs the filename from the formula `"./" & [foldername] & "/" & [filebasename]`.

Furthermore you can use internal variables, accessed via `${}` to refern to certain paths relating to the transformation, for example `${Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}`.